# How do I write a regex for this...?

Tags: regex

Given a string in the format `someName_v0001`, how do I write a regex that can give me the name (the bit before _v) and version (the bit after _v), where the version suffix is optional.

e.g. for the input

```
input => (name, version)
abc_v0001 => (abc, 0001)
abc_v10000 => (abc, 10000)
abc_vwx_v0001 => (abc_vwx,1)
abc => (abc, null)
```

I've tried this...

```
(.*)_v\(d*)
```

... but I don't know how to handle the case of the optional version suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*?)(?:_v0*(\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fNKrGp/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:_v0*(\d+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `_v` - a `_v` substring
  - `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
  - `(\d+)` - Capturing group 2: any one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(.*)_v([\d]*)
```

The first capture group is name, the second is version.

```
() => capture result
.* => any character
_v => the string "_v" this should compensate for the special cases
[\d]* => any number of any digits
```

Answer (score 0):

To say that a character (or group of characters) is optional, use a `?` after it.

For example `ABC?` would match both “AB” and “ABC”, while `AB(CD)?` would match both “AB” and “ABCSD”.

I assume you want to make the “_v” part of the version optional as well. In that case, you need to enclose it in a *non-capturing* group, `(?: )`, so that you can make it optional using `?` without also capturing it.

The correct regex for your scenario is `(.*)(?:_v(\d+))?`. Capture group 1 will be the name and capture group 2 will be the version, if it exists.